# Show div on top of Kendo for Angular Dialog

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hjxv1) I have a Kendo for Angular Dialog. In the dialog there's a div with `position:absolute` that I need to show on top of the dialog, not inside it, and the dialog shouldn't have any scroll bars. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-dialog title="Kendo Dialog" 
              style="position:relative;overflow:visible"
             [width]="400" [height]="100">
            <div id="div1">Some text in the div</div>
        </kendo-dialog>
    `,
    styles: [`
         #div1 {
           position: absolute;
           top: 20px;
           left: 240px;
           width: 300px;
           z-index: 99990;
           background-color: #f0f0f0;
           border: 2px solid blue;
         }
    `]

})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the component styles:

```
    my-app .k-window-content {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
```

Comment: Great one. Fixed the same issue i was facing, along with this: .k-grid td { overflow:visible } as I had to overflow from my cell :)